# How does this famous JAPH work?

Tags: perl

```
not exp log srand xor s qq qx xor
s x x length uc ord and print chr
ord for qw q join use sub tied qx
xor eval xor print qq q q xor int
eval lc q m cos and print chr ord
for qw y abs ne open tied hex exp
ref y m xor scalar srand print qq
q q xor int eval lc qq y sqrt cos
and print chr ord for qw x printf
each return local x y or print qq
s s and eval q s undef or oct xor
time xor ref print chr int ord lc
foreach qw y hex alarm chdir kill
exec return y s gt sin sort split
```

Like any other JAPH, this prints out "just another perl hacker". But I'd like a semi-detailed dissection of what behavior this particular JAPH is taking advantage of to work - I'm no good at Perl, but some JAPHs I can read through... this, no way.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=290623

Comment: @toolic Ah, shoulda checked the Dojo - the perl monks solved it again

Comment: It is disappointing, but not surprising, that [vim-perl](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl) syntax highlighting does not highlight that correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really not that hard once you understood the basics. Here are some hints to get you started:

```
not exp log srand
        # srand = 1, exp o log = id, not 1 = 0

        # $_ = undef
xor s// /x                      
        # $_ = ' '
xor s/ / length uc ord and print chr ord for qw q join use sub tied q/
        # $_ = ' length uc ord and print chr ord for qw q join use sub tied q'

xor eval
```

Note that `chr ord` of a string returns the first character and `join use sub tied` in the end has the first characters `j`, `u`, `s`, `t`. :)

Just for fun, I wrote an extension of this famous japhs years ago:

```
not srand xor s qq qx xor s x x length uc
ord and print uc chr ord for qw q join qx
xor eval xor lc eval qq x abs cos ord and
print chr ord for qw q use substr tied qx
xor print qq q q xor int eval lc qq m cos
and print chr ord for qw y abs ne or tied
hex exp ref y m xor scalar srand print qq
q q xor sin abs eval q x log srand ord or
printf uc chr ord foreach qw q package qx
xor sqrt eval lc qq y sqrt cos and printf
chr ord for qw x each return local x y or
print qq s s and uc exp eval q s undef or
oct xor time xor ref print chr int ord lc
for qw y hex alarm chdir kill exec return
y s xor log exp eval q x print chr length
join qw y length for map substr chr shift
y x or sqrt abs ord lc and eval print q q
q and s q q lcfirst chr eval log shift qx
```

printing the real<sup>™</sup> string `"Just another Perl hacker,\n"`.

And this is a smaller version containing a german christmas greeting:

```
not exp log srand xor s qq qx xor
s x x length uc ord and print chr
ord for qw q find redo ord helpme
eval scalar qx xor eval xor print
q q q xor int eval lc q m cos and
print chr ord for qw y flock each
s tell y m gt sin ref study split
```

Comment: Ahhh - the hint revealed it. I see now, heh.

Answer (score 12):

The first appearance of this JAPH appears to be on http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=290607

As the PerlMonks thread states, now there is an automatic tool which does this kind of obfuscation: http://namazu.org/~takesako/ppencode/

You can read it's [source code](http://namazu.org/~takesako/ppencode/ppencode), but reverse engineering is so much funnier :)

For instance, here's the code to print a whitespace:

```
stas@bp0907:~$ perl -e 'length q chmod lc and print chr ord q q eq'
 stas@bp0907:~$
```

Is this the only way of printing a ' ' character? Actually, no, refreshing produces:

```
stas@bp0907:~$ perl -e 'oct oct hex ord q else and print chr ord q q q'
 stas@bp0907:~$
```

Cool, both variants end on the same `and print chr ord q q ...`. So everything before that must evaluate to true value and is there only to dust our eyes.

Then, `print chr ord` can be simplified to simply `print` in that context, as `chr(ord($str))` only picks the first character from `$str`. So it boils down to:

```
stas@bp0907:~$ perl -e 'print q q eq'
 stas@bp0907:~$
```

`q q eq` is an unusual representation of the `q` quote, it is more easily recognized as `q ( e)`. The same logic works for the original, even more obfuscated JAPH: `print chr ord
for qw y ... y` will pick everything between `y` characters and separated by whitespaces as an array.

---

There is a related topic, which concerns Perl code shaped as an ASCII art. There is a CPAN module for that, too: [Acme::EyeDrops](http://cpan.me/Acme::EyeDrops)